# Magento - Display image only if present

Tags: attributes, template, product-images

in Magento i have an attribute called "sagoma". It is a media attribute that shows an image.
This is the code that I use to show the image:

```
<img id="image-main"
    class="gallery-image visible"
    src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'sagoma') ?>"
    alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
    title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
```

I would like to show this html only if the attribute "sagoma" is not empty. If empty i will not show nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $sagoma = $_product->getData('sagoma');?>
<?php if ($sagoma && $sagoma != 'no_selection') : ?>
    <img id="image-main"
        class="gallery-image visible"
        src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'sagoma') ?>"
        alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
        title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
<?php endif;?>
```